# turning blob file into a image file

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

im working with sakila DB and trying to turn THE blob file in there to an image file.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT picture 
FROM staff 
LIMIT 1    -- or WHERE staff_id = 1 (or 2)
INTO DUMPFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\picture.png';
```

Check [`secure_file_priv`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable previously.

- If its value is non-empty (and contains the path to some directory) then the output file path must be equal to this directory.
- If its value is empty string than the path may be any.
- If it is set to NULL or to a value which is not existing directory then you cannot save the output to file - create specified directory or reconfigure server.